Correct way to import data with ObjectId / "$oid" into mongo-unit via mongoose, for unit tests?
I have some data which was exported from a production database, for the purposes of finding a bug. The is in .json files which I have put under test/fixture/data.
I am importing them into an instance of MongoDB created by mongo-unit, using mongoose (An old version, I know. It's not my code) for a unit-test setup for a Node JS app.
I've had trouble importing this data in such a way that the data can be queried by the code under test. The unit tests do work for an installed MongoDB server, with this data imported via Compass
From reading up on this subject, there seems to be 3 different ways to handle the "ObjectId" situation, and 2 possible ways of loading the data, giving 6 combinations.
I am setting up the data to import using:
const my_data = require('./fixture/data/my_data.json');
export default mongoose.model('my_data', TheSchema);

Then possible methods of loading are:

await importedSchema.insertMany(my_data, function(err,result) {...});

await mongoUnit.load(my_data);


Note: The data is a Json array of Json object, but when using this second style of loading, the data in my_data.json has to be wrapped with the Collection name:
{ "my_data":  // <-- Need to specify the Collection name
[
    ...
]}

The possible ways to handle "ObjectId" are:

"_id": ObjectId("abc...def"),
"_id": { "$oid": "abc...def" },
"_id": "abc...def",

The results are:

insertMany() with ObjectId style:

Exception during run: SyntaxError: <project>/test/fixture/data/my_data.json: Unexpected token 'O', ..."
 "_id": ObjectId(""... is not valid JSON


insertMany() with "$oid" style:

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ '$oid': '66cc910cdf4388a8582bf6ca' }" (type Object) at path "_id"
        at ObjectId.cast (<project>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:248:11)
      stringValue: `"{ '$oid': 'abc...def' }"`,
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'ObjectId',
      value: [Object],
      path: '_id',
      reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
              at new ObjectID (<project>/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:59:11)
      valueType: 'Object'

This comes with other errors such as:
    created_date: CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$date': '2024-08-26T14:28:28.334Z' }" (type Object) at path "created_date"


insertMany() with simple string style:

    created_date: CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$date': '2024-08-26T14:28:28.334Z' }" (type Object) at path "created_date"
        at SchemaDate.cast (<project>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:354:11)
      stringValue: `"{ '$date': '2024-08-26T14:28:28.334Z' }"`,
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'date',
      value: [Object],
      path: 'created_date',
      reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
      
        assert.ok(false)


mongoUnit.load() with ObjectId style -
Identical response as using insertMany():

Exception during run: SyntaxError: <project>/test/fixture/data/my_data.json: Unexpected token 'O', ..."
 "_id": ObjectId(""... is not valid JSON


mongoUnit.load() with "$oid" style:

     MongoBulkWriteError: _id fields may not contain '$'-prefixed fields: $oid is not valid for storage.
      at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (node_modules/mongo-unit/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:927:22)


mongoUnit.load() with simple string style:
The data loads without error, but nothing is found by query.

If you login via mongosh and query, you get:

> db.my_data.countDocuments()
4315
> db.my_data.find().limit(1)
[
  {
    _id: 'abc...def',
    other_data: { ........

> db.my_data.find({"_id": ObjectId("abc...def")})

> db.my_data.find({"_id": "abc...def"})
[
  {
    _id: 'abc...def',
    other_data: { ........

However, in the javascript for the query functions, I find such code as:
let firstStageQuery = {
    is_archived: false,
    ...(xId && xId !== "" && { "_id": ObjectId(xId) }),
};

So the service's queries are coming up empty for this loaded data, but they do work in production.

After an enormous amount of trial, error and research, I finally worked it out.
The solution requires installtion of BSO Parser.
Having installed it, you can then do this in your Node.js test file:
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { EJSON } from 'bson';
import mongoUnit from 'mongo-unit';
....
const my_date = EJSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/fixture/data/my_data.json') );
....
await mongoUnit.load(my_data);

Where my_data.json is in the style
{ "my_data":  // <-- Collection Name
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "abc...def"
  },
  .....
}]}

